# Spring OAuth2: How can I only allow user to access /rest/users/{id} with his own id?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Sometimes we only allow user to access his own info by calling /rest/users/{id}, How can I implement this under spring OAuth2?

Thanks.

Comment: you can go through this article which provides the steps  in detail https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I read this article before, but it doesn't answer my question. But thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Principal is your user id, use @PreAuthorize annotation :

```
@PreAuthorize("#id.equals(principal)")
public void myMethod(Long id)
```